# Python: Create a number of empty Dictionaries from a file with unique name

Tags: python, dictionary

There are several ways of creating a empty Dictionary in Python, for example:

```
#method 1
Alan = {}
#method 2
John = dict()
```

I want to create a number of Dictionaries to store personal information of a group of employees. A person's name will be used as a unique name in creating the empty Dictionary. Employees name are stored into a file (info.txt) and each line will only have one name.

```
#info.txt
Alan
John
Fiona
... x Repeat N times
```

The number of name or entry in the file is unpredictable, so I wish to have a flexible code to handle this type of scenario.
My code will read every single line and try to create a empty Dictionary for each employee. However, my codes does not work because the Dictionary is not defined.

```
#read employee name from file
infoFile = open("info.txt","r")

#read every line and create Dictionary for each employee
for infoFileLine in infoFile:
    if not infoFileLine.strip():
        pass

    else:
        print("%s" %infoFileLine)
        designFileLine = dict()

#update employee personal info
Alan["Age"] = 36
Alan["Height"] = 180
John["Age"] = 36
John["Height"] = 180
```

I am new to Python, so what is wrong with my code above? Or is there any other better way of doing it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better use a `dict` of `dict`s, like `user_details = {}; user_details['Alan'] = {'Height': 190, 'Age': 36}`

Comment: Beware of the wrong indentation from `if not infoFileLine.strip()` to `designFileLine = dict()`

Comment: This is a good question most programmers come across when learning to code.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a master dictionary that contains other dictionarys. Here is a brief example:

```
master = {}
names = ["Alan", "Peter"]

for n in names:
    master[n] = {}
print(master)
```

And the output is:

```
{'Alan': {}, 'Peter': {}}
```

Just change my `names` array for a `file.readLines()` method and it should work.